# Use Request.QueryString in WinForm Application C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

how to use `Request.QueryString` in winform 
my code is c#
i know `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString` is a solution 
but i can not understand
my sample is

```
OAuthTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret, Request.QueryString["oauth_token"],Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Build a URL with query string parameters?

Comment: The best way is to check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx).